# java.util.Enumeration in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How do I properly call `exists` for `java.util.Enumeration`? I cannot change the source, it's from `HttpServletRequest`.

This (unrelated) code works:

```
val a = List("One", "Two", "Three")
a exists (_ contains "T")
```

But why this code cannot be compiled:

```
import collection.JavaConversions.enumerationAsScalaIterator
enumerationAsScalaIterator(req.getHeaderNames[String])[String] exists (_ contains "T")
```

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE. The above code doesn't show any error in the editor but will throw error when compiled:

**error: ';' expected but '[' found.
enumerationAsScalaIterator(req.getHeaderNames[String])[String] exists (_ contains "T")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do it for `HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames` is the good old loop:

```
val headers = req.getHeaderNames
while (headers.hasMoreElements) {
if (headers.nextElement.asInstanceOf[String] contains "T")
  return FOO
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
import collection.JavaConversions.enumerationAsScalaIterator

req.getHeaderNames() exists (_ contains "T")
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `enumerationAsScalaIterator[String](req.getHeaderNames[String]) exists (_ contains "T")` (or use it implicitly, [as Pablo Fernandez suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998801/java-util-enumeration-in-scala/7999200#7999200)). No idea why it wouldn't show an error in the editor, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your second [String] here:
req.getHeaderNames[String])[String]
Isn't needed, and isn't valid Scala.
Try

```
enumerationAsScalaIterator(req.getHeaderNames[String]) exists (_ contains "T")
```

Better yet, enumerationAsScalaIterator is available implicitly, so you should be able to just do:

```
req.getHeaderNames exists (_ contains "T")
```

Comment: Same with above, it produces "Cannot resolve symbol contains" in the IDE.